# Sql Server select query : Sum and Last input by month of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this :

```
-------------------------------------------------
Id  | Date                    | Paid  | Remaining |
--------------------------------------------------
 1  | 2020-02-02 12:57:59.950 |500.00 |NULL       |
 2  | 2020-02-02 12:57:59.950 |20.00  |NULL       |
 3  | 2020-02-19 12:10:59.950 |300.00 |NULL       |
 4  | 2020-02-20 12:10:59.950 |100.00 |150.00     |
 5  | 2020-02-27 12:10:59.950 |100.00 |70.00      |
 6  | 2020-03-02 12:57:59.950 |500.00 |50.00      |
 7  | 2020-03-19 12:10:59.950 |300.00 |NULL       |
 8  | 2020-03-20 12:10:59.950 |100.00 |20.00      |
 9  | 2020-03-27 12:10:59.950 |60.00  |60.00      |
```

I want to do a select query , that return for each date group by month:

- Total paid ( Sum)
- Last remaining by month

---

```
| Date        | TotalPaid   | LastRemaining |
----------------------------------------
| 2020-02-01  |1020.00      | 70.00
| 2020-03-01  |960.00       | 60.00
```

Comment: How the date in output 2020-02-01 will appear?

Comment: @SurajKumar : CONVERT(date,myDate)

Comment: I am saying that date is not available in the sample data so how it will come in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select yyyymm, sum(paid),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then remaining end) as last_remaining
from (select t.*, yyyymm,
             row_number() over (partition by v.yyyymm order by date desc) as seqnum             
      from t cross apply
           (values (datefromparts(year(date), month(date), 1))
           ) v(yyyymm)
     ) t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

You can actually also do this with no subqueries, but it is messier:

```
select distinct v.yyyymm,
       sum(t.paid) over (partition by v.yyyymm) as paid,
       first_value(t.remaining) over (partition by v.yyyymm order by t.date desc) as last_remaining
from t cross apply
      (values (datefromparts(year(date), month(date), 1))
      ) v(yyyymm);
```

This uses `select distinct` with a window function as a work-around for the last of a "first()"/"last()" aggregation function.

Comment: If i add onther colmun like CustomerId , how it would be the query ( means ; query group by Date ,CustomerId, TotalPaid , LastRemaing  per month per customer ?

Comment: @ZiedR . . . This is an aggregation query.  You can aggregate by the customer id.  If that doesn't do what you want, you should ask another question, with clear sample data and desired results.